# How to do a global highscore table in my Libgdx game?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am developing a game in libgdx, 
I want to do a global highscore table. I tried to find some tutorials about this subject and I coudn't find even one that explain step by step how to do that on libgdx platform - (android).

Comment: Add more details to your question. You want to know how to show score table or how to store data for score table? You can also read this topic, there are lost of ready code samples of using Scene2D for table score there: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=31331.0

Comment: Thank you for replaying, I want to know how to store data for score table. Is there a tutorial on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see such tutorial, but I recommend you to store your score data in JSON. I will give you global few tips, if you will have some questions just ask.

1. You can read this tutorial in order to understand how to store data in files http://steigert.blogspot.be/2012/03/5-libgdx-tutorial-files.html.
2. You also have this official tutorial in order to understand how to work with JSON in libgdx https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-%26-writing-JSON#Writing_Object_Graphs

You should crete JSON file for example `scoretable.json`. Every time you want to update score table just write changes to this file, if you want to display the table to user just parse file and show it with the GUI as you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for replaying! 
I took a look at the tutorials you gave above, but they are only give the knowlenge about how to store data in json files. My english is very bad, so I will try to explain what I meant to by give an example:

For example I am a user that download the app, I broke my record, now I want that my highscore data will be saved in a json file, but how can an other user from other country can also see my record? 

I hope that now you understand what I meant, again , sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Now I really understand what you want. For creating online score table  for android app you should use: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/games.html .Here is a tutorial how to intigrate Google Game Services in libgdx: http://theinvader360.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/google-play-game-services-tutorial-example.html  This library form Google will do exactly what you want.

Comment: @AlonZilberman What should I do if I want to develop cross platform and not only android app? Do I also use Google?

Comment: As far as I know Google Play Game Services works also on IOS devices and even in WEB. You can check details here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/

Answer (score 1):

This is my game
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.fainosag.nicujamp

To make the online tables i just went to http://www.serversfree.com/ made a free account, set up a new server, and using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/ i upload or download what i want.

I use JSON to keep the data all in one, and for now is working very good for me, i got top 20 all time and top 20 today.

If you want to make a big game with a lot of downloads, you might want to buy a server from a hosting company.

Comment: There are plenty of ready solutions for online scoring. Most of big games used Google Game Services. It handles all work for you(easy log in for users, score tables, competition with friends, achivments etc) I think there is no sense to create your own solution if free, fixable and easy to implement solution already exist.

Comment: I didn't read much about google play services, as I saw , google makes the table..so i don't think you get just get the string that you want, that contains the top, and implement in your own way in your game..I may be wrong but, I like to do stuff my own way when I can